# QGIS plugin "Load raster to PostGIS"

Tags: postgis, raster, qgis-plugins

I tried to find QGIS plugin "Load raster to PostGIS" but I could not find anything in Plugins section in QGIS. Is there any external resource where is possible download this plugin and after that install in QGIS 3.4?